# Best way to build Settings.apk

Tags: android, apk, decompiling, lg

Hey people thanks for taking the time to take a look at my question. Ok so i'm planning on Re-building the Settings.apk on my Lg Device (e425f) and adding my own addtions but i have no idea what to use, i done some research and Found "Virtuous 10 Studio" and "ApkTool", so which is best and furthermore are we permitted to Rebuild apks budled with Android Devices ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the complete source code of android, and you have your environment set for building android complete code, you can build individual applications like "Settings" as well.

This link will help you to set up build environment:

http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

You need to use "mm" command in ubuntu to build individual apps.

Yes, it should be fine to rebuild apps after makeing changes to prebuild android apps.

Alternatively, you can simply use Android developer tools (Eclipse with android SDT plugin) to build apps.

This link will help with this:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Answer (score 0):

Android is open-source (Apache license) which means you are free to browse and re-use the source code in any way provided you respect the terms of the Apache license when redistributing.

The source code for settings in Android can be found here:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/tree/master/src/com/android/settings

I would advise using Eclipse and the Android SDK to build Android Applications.

Comment: Will i be able to build the settings app from source on windows in eclipse ?

Comment: @user2254087 Probably not without making a number of changes.  As covered here before, the packaged apps are not generally intended to build against the SDK, and the AOSP versions typically require modification to do so.  But it is unclear if the AOSP version would even meet your needs, or once built, be install able.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Apologies, this specific part of the code is actually "licensed under the Apache license http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0", but Apache is more or less the same as GPL and is in fact compatible with GPL, so my advice is sound and is not "erroneous". Anyway I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: No, Apache is by no means *more or less* the same as GPL - especially where *downstream vendors* are involved, as they appear to be in this case.  In a marked difference from parallelism with the GPL, it is unclear that the apache license *even applies* to the device-specific version of code of interest to the poster.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Actually it does apply if you read the source files I linked to you will see that it is clearly stated in each of them. Also that's your opinion, my opinion is that it is more or less the same, because the differences are trivial. In fairness the license probably more similar to BSD than GPL, but it's an abstract description anyway so your objection to my use of terms is unnecessary.

Comment: You linked to an unofficial copy of the AOSP source files - but those *probably are not* quite what is on a **vendor** device.  And the fact that what is on the device *can have a different license from the AOSP version* is precisely what is so different from the way in which a GPL upstream license would have to be preserved downstream.